# Render QtQuick into a texture of an external OpenGL application

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qml

We have an application that loads OpenGL functions via GLEW and WGL.
We aim to use QML created UI on top of it within the same window.
We had a look into the QQuickRenderControl but we are not sure how to link the OpenGL context to Qt and if the loaded OpenGL function pointers are compatible with the one used by Qt.

We have already looked into the [RenderControl example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-rendercontrol-example.html) but the difference here is that the OpenGL context and loading are managed by Qt. We want to manage it on our own without Qt dependencies.

We use Qt 5.11.

**edit:** Both our OpenGL and Qt are in the same process. Just to not confuse you.

Comment: @dtech thanks for the comment. However, we are using just a single application. For now we are able to run both our OpenGL stuff and Qt together, but not in the same window.

Comment: What about:http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/07/07/qt-webgl-streaming-merged/ ?